# Lookup category based on partial part code match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've experimented with a few formulas using VLOOKUP, LOOKUP and SEARCH to achieve what I want but haven't quite succeeded. Can anyone shed some light on the following.

Sheet 1, Column A has the following part code examples:

```
ABC-4543ED
VG3454325
VG7654-76457-788
ABCD-78567565
DSWE1-FRG546346
0012-52458-85698
```

Next to each of these in column B, I want to assign a category. The category selection should be based on a lookup from Sheet 2 as follows:

Sheet 2 has two Columns A (Code) and B (Category)

```
A          B
ABC-       Category 1
ABCD-      Category 2
VG         Category 3
DSWE1-     Category 4
0012-      Category 5
```

The result on Sheet 1 that I want to end up with from a lookup is:

```
A                    B
ABC-4543ED           Category 1
VG3454325            Category 3
VG7654-76457-788     Category 3
ABCD-78567565        Category 2
DSWE1-FRG546346      Category 4
0012-52458-85698     Category 5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

=LOOKUP(1E+100,MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5&"*",A1,0),Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5)

Answer (score 0):

This formula uses both sumproduct to determine the matches and index to return your category.

```
=INDEX(#CategoryRange#, SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1,LEN(#CodeRange#))=#CodeRange#),
ROW(#CodeRange#)))
```

Just replace the `#CategoryRange#` and `#CodeRange#` with your cell range or named range.